# How to get rid of the Debug output "symbol loaded"

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, settings

When i debug my program i get a bunch of notifications which i don't need.
[image]

> "Assemblyname.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Assemblyname.vshost.exe): "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net... .dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.

So i searched on the web on how to deactivate this notifications, but i'm currently unable to find some useful information on how to achieve this.

**Do somebody know how to disable this output ?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can also right click inside Output Window and uncheck Module Load Messages

[image: Module Load Messages]

Answer (score 4):

- Tools
- Options
- Debugging
- Output Window
- Set "Module Load Messages" to *Off*